# How do I remove the gap in a Godot HBoxContainer between items?

Tags: godot-4

I created a HBoxContainer and put two ViewportContainers into it.

They line up side by side, but there is a gap of a couple of pixels between them.

How do I tell Godot that I don't want any spacing/margin between the items in a HBoxContainer?

Answer (score 2):

Ah I found it you have to go to `Theme Overrides > Constants > Separation` and enable it.